# How to connect a microcontroller to PS/2 port as the PS/2-keyboard?

Tags: voltage, keyboard, ps2

The voltage of output signals of my CPLD MAX II board is 3 volts. Can I connect this board to open collector of [PS/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_port) motherboard-MCU?

[image: snippet of schematic]

So, if I want to send a "zero" signal, I'm sending "one" to the transistor base, right?

Comment: With other words: you'll need to define which microcontroller you actually have (an FPGA is not a microcontroller, to begin with...) and how much effort you're willing to go through to make things work.

Comment: Yes, I have max II board with only 1.5 volts output and as far as I know  it's must be over 2.5v to switch 5v logic MCU (motherboard MCU).

Comment: Please **edit** your question to include this crucial info. Also, the MAX II isn't an FPGA, either, but a CPLD; are you sure you don't simply want to build this using a microcontroller? (Building something using a CPLD is way more complicated than just coding a software for a microcontroller, and also, serial protocols are really what microcontrollers are meant to handle. Microcontroller boards that would suffice for what you want to do cost < 10€.)

Comment: oh yes, i'm sure (and i have a microcontroller)

Comment: :) Would it be  OK if I asked you why you'd want to implement something as slow as PS/2 with a relatively complex and expensive CPLD? Sounds like an interesting application!

Comment: it's for CPLD-version of [Little Man Computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_man_computer)

Comment: Little Man Computer - CPU simulator [here](https://peterhigginson.co.uk/lmc/)

Comment: oh, that's rather cool!

Answer (score 1):

No, unless it can tolerate the 5V signals of the motherboard PS/2 interface.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where the pullup resistor is connected.

If the pullup is to 3.3V and the motherboard connection is truly open-collector then you should not damage the microcontroller.

If the pullup is connected to 5V then the open-collector output of the microcontroller will be driven to 5V at times, which may damage the microcontroller. See the microcontroller datasheet for specific details.

Comment: Motherboards have pull-ups to 5V. Keyboards too.

Comment: @Justme Fair enough. I thought the question deserved a more complete explanation, since Marcus Muller answered with a blanket "yes".

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I'm sorry (honestly, a bit at least), but the chance to say "OK, you're not specifying what you're using to what end under what constraints, so um, help yourself to a 'yes, that's possible'" was just too tempting. As it turns out in the comments under the question, OP's microcontroller is actually a CPLD.